# How to insert tab using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

I'm using iTextSharp to generate pdfs in my .net application.
I'm stuck at a small yet very simple place that I can't seem to figure out.
I'm generating table using PdfPTable and adding cells to them.

In one of these cells I want add say about 3 tabs in it.
I have tried following 2 code but not giving me desired output.

```
table.AddCell(new Phrase("\t\tDate:", sampleFont)); //Date:

table.AddCell(Chunk.TAB + Chunk.TAB + new Phrase("Date:", sampleFont)); //TABTABDate:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unluckily, `iTextSharp` does not support `Tab`, but you can use `Paragraph` `Paragraph.IndentationLeft` instead.

You also can use `cell.PaddingLeft` for table cell.

Comment: How can I integrate this im the table cell?

Comment: @ConfusedProgrammer: you cannot add Paragraph into table cell?